# powershell - the output displayed does not match the csv output

Tags: windows, powershell, server

The output to the csv only show the servers that report N/A for the OS, but the output to the screen includes the OS information for all windows server OS.

Here's my code:

```
$servers = Get-Content "ServerList.txt"

 
$results = foreach ($server in $servers) {
   $result1 = Test-Connection "$server.domain1.com" -Count 1 -Quiet

 
   if ($result1) {
       $osInfo = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       $ipAddress = (Resolve-DnsName $server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1).IPAddress
       $output = [PSCustomObject]@{
           Server = $server
           Domain = "domain1.com"
           Status = "Up"
           OS = if ($osInfo) { ($osInfo.Name -replace '^Microsoft\s+Windows\s+', '') -replace '\|.*$' } else { "N/A" }
           IP = if ($ipAddress) { $ipAddress } else { "N/A" }
       }
       Write-Host "`t${server}: $($output.Status) - $($output.OS) - $($output.IP)"
       $output
   }
   else {
       Write-Host "`t${server}: Down"
   }
}

 
$results | Sort-Object Domain | Export-Csv "ServerList.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I don't know what to try to fix this.

*UPDATE*

I added some logging and try/catch code (as per ChatGPT).  This actually worked and having the error log is great.  Thanks for the suggestion @mclayton.

```
$servers = Get-Content "ServerList2.txt"
$logFile = "ServerList2.log"
$csvFile = "ServerList2.csv"
 
$results = foreach ($server in $servers) {
   Write-Host "`nTesting server: $server"
   $output = [PSCustomObject]@{
       Server = $server
       Domain = "domain1.com"
       Status = "Down"
       OS = "N/A"
       IP = "N/A"
   }
 
   # Test connection
   $result1 = Test-Connection "$server.domain1.com" -Count 1 -Quiet
   if ($result1) {
       $output.Status = "Up"
 
       # Resolve DNS name
       try {
           $dnsResult = Resolve-DnsName $server -ErrorAction Stop | Select-Object -First 1
           $output.IP = $dnsResult.IPAddress
       }
       catch {
           Write-Warning "Failed to resolve DNS name for server ${server}: $_"
           Add-Content $logFile "$(Get-Date) - Failed to resolve DNS name for server ${server}: $_"
       }
 
       # Get OS info
       try {
           $osInfo = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ErrorAction Stop
           $output.OS = ($osInfo.Name -replace '^Microsoft\s+Windows\s+', '') -replace '\|.*$'
       }
       catch {
           Write-Warning "Failed to get OS info for server ${server}: $_"
           Add-Content $logFile "$(Get-Date) - Failed to get OS info for server ${server}: $_"
       }
 
       Write-Host "`t$($output.Server): $($output.Status) - $($output.OS) - $($output.IP)"
   }
   else {
       Write-Host "`t$($output.Server): $($output.Status)"
   }
 
   $output
}
 
$results | Export-Csv $csvFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8 -Append -Force -Delimiter ','
 
Write-Host "`nResults written to $csvFile"
```

Comment: There’s probably an error being swallowed in your ```if( $osInfo ) …``` - try adding some logging with ```write-host``` to display some variable values on-screen so you can verify your assumptions (e.g. does ```$osInfo``` even have a ```Name``` property? Is your regex valid? Etc…

Comment: At a guess, it’s probably because your second ```-replace``` doesn’t have a substitution argument (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.3#replacement-operator), but for your own benefit it would be a good exercise to work out how to use debugging / logging techniques to zero in on this yourself :-)

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm a newbie at best to PowerShell even though technically I've been using it sporadically for years.  I honestly don't know how to debug, but I will start googling and see what I can come up with.  Thanks.